# echo html code that inserted to mysql database using prepare method of pdo

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

i would like to echo a html code that i inserted that to the mysql database using prepare method of pdo. the prepare method add somethings to html code string like backslash('\') to quotation sign.

i add the html code to the mysql table with following code:

```
$result=$this->link->prepare($query);
$rslt= $result->execute($params);
```

and echo that with the following code:

```
<?php foreach($model_data['post'] as $post){?>
        <h2><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h2>
        <p>
          <?php echo $post['body']; ?>
        </p>
<?php } ?>
```

so when i echo the stored html code string on page, the added sign's like backslashes don't allow to execute html code properly.

how can i remove the prepare pdo added sign's when echo the html code? thanks...

Comment: you could wrap it into a `<pre>` element ...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
echo htmlentities($yourString);
```